# How to validate SSL request in AWS Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, ssl, dns

I've deployed an app to Elastic Beanstalk and now in order to have htpps I need to add port 443 in ELB and mention the SSL certificate. Now as I don't have one I'm trying to create. I got the domain after deploying frontend to Firebase. I found that after requesting the certificate I need to create a CNAME record and use values provided in AWS requested certificate in order to validate it I just can't seem to find the way to create it in Firebase. Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated

I tried to create the cname in AWS Route 53 hosted zones and expected the ssl to be validated but I think I need to create the record in Firebase I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It has to be a domain name that you own https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain. You can't create SSL certificates for domain names you don't own. If you are trying to create an SSL certificate for the free subdomains you get with Firebase, I don't think that is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to identify where your DNS records are being managed. Once you get the records added at the right place your certificate will be validated successfully.

Comment: How do I identify where the DNS records are managed??